# Searching for backslash + string in javascript via regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex, firebug

I've got a file reference in JS and I need to parse it via regex. All as I want is to get the 'C' character that follows a backslash.  Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

```
var str = "C:\Course\folder\file.txt";
str.match(/\\C/g);
```

If I run this in firebug or similar tool, I get nothing back.

Comment: Sorry, what are you trying to do again? Do you just want to check for the existence of `\C`?

Comment: You have not mentioned about what result you are expecting from the reg-ex??

Comment: Thanks, guys, I see the problem, it's my broken 'str' in the first place!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

Because the string you've quoted doesn't contain backslashes. It has an invalid escape sequence (`\C`) resulting in just `C` and two formfeeds (`\f`), but no backslashes.

If you have actual backslashes, it works:

```
var str = "C:\\Course\\folder\\file.txt";
str.match(/\\C/g);
```

Comment: @StefanRay: No, of course not. You only have to escape backslashes in string *literals*. In a string literal, \\ puts *one* actual backslash into the actual string in memory. If your string is coming to you from somewhere and actually has backslashes in it, your `match` call will work. I suspect your problem is just that you're testing it using string literals and not escaping the backslash in the literal.

Comment: Thanks, I see the problem now, it's a malformed string in the first place.

Comment: @StefanRay: Right, in memory your literal gives you `C:Course<FF>older<FF>ile.txt` where `<FF>` stands for formfeed. :-)